# npm ci giving Conflicting peer dependency

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, npm-install, npm-ci

I am trying to install the dependencies from docker file with command `RUN npm ci`. But I am getting the following error `Conflicting peer dependencies. Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.`. In my local project I have overcome this issue while running `npm install --force`. How I can fix this inside the docker while building and running this command `RUN npm ci`.

As I have understood npm ci will look it either from the package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json. But still facing this issue. Cannot figure it out what is causing this.

Comment: Can you fix the dependencies (without a "force" option) in your non-Docker development environment, commit the `package.json` and `package-lock.json`/`yarn.lock` files to source control, then rebuild your Docker images with the correct lock file?

Comment: @DavidMaze in my non-Docker development environment I am also facing this issue  (without a "force" option)

Comment: @DavidMaze without using --force option in my non-Docker development environment I am getting ```Could not resolve dependency: Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.```

Comment: For now I have fixed it with installing the dependencies with npm version to 6. Looks like I need to workout to update the rest of the dependencies to make it work without --force if npm version is >6

Answer (score 4):

They introduce a breaking changes in **npm@8.6** (*yes! a minor version bump, with a major breaking changes*).

The update changes the behavior of package installation, both from `npm install` and `npm ci`.

Previously, the `npm ci` command would blindly install whatever was in the lock file. AS IS, it will validates both the `package-lock.json` and `package.json` is in a consistent state.

You could read more about the issue here: [github.com/npm/cli/issues/4998](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4998), [github.com/npm/cli/issues/5113](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5113), and [github.com/npm/cli/issues/4664](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4664)

Answer (score 1):

I also started to get this error on pipe. What is interesting I always have had peer dependency conflict but it was only appearing with npm install. The best option is to run script with flag --legacy-peer-deps it will skip checking peer dependency. Peer dependency should be installed manually in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

> npm i --force

solved my problem

Note : I got :
added 482 packages, and audited 483 packages in 3m
Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.